# Webview com vídeo

Tags: android, android-webview

Opa galera boa tarde, eu estou ultimamente mexendo com webviews, eu estava procurando na net um modo de rodar videos das urls tipo site, que tem uma postagem e nessa postagem tem um vídeo, dei uma pesquisada e vi isso :

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

ele seta no webview um cliente do chrome e assim roda o vídeo de um link por exemplo...

Queria saber como se faz para na aplicação implementar um player melhor, sei que envolve mais coisas além do webview mas até agora não encontrei

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.studiosol.player.letras

esse link acima é do app do Letras nele você pode ver as letras e vídeos das musicas, eu queria algo que me trouxesse esse [player de vídeo] que essa app usa, acredito que possa ser uma API, mas posso ta falando bobeira, nele tem tem as opções de resolução do vídeo tipo HD OU FULL HD, abaixo tem prints que mostram oque eu quero dizer ,quem tiver um tutorial de como fazer algo parecido irá me ajudar e muito...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não não, acho que escrevi de uma maneira incorreta, irei colocar umas imagens na postagem para que possa entender melhor...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu queria apenas o player que vem ...

Comment: Vou explicar calma, acabei de postar as prints, esse APP do letras é um app de musicas, nele tem esse player de video do youtube, oque eu quero saber é como implementar esse tipo de player dentro de uma WEBVIEW o app é só pra ter um exemplo, eu não tenho nada a ver com esse app, muito menos quero fazer uma Intent com app Letras...

Comment: Sim acho que entendi, mas é que você citou coisas extras, então por isto estou tentando ver quais requisitos, de certa forma acho que é possivel sim (inclusive eu estava a ler sobre isto a alguns dias), eu apenas queria ver quais as necessidades, pois se eu respondo com um exemplo minimo pode ser que venham outras necessidades, ae terei retrabalho para editar a resposta. Deixe a pergunta como esta, vou tentar formular um exemplo, ainda não experimentei, mas pelo que li ao menos é possivel usar fullscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você ira precisar utilizar a API do Youtube.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/?hl=pt-br

O processo parece complicado mas não é, implementei no meu aplicativo em alguns minutos.

Detelha: não conseguir adicionar direto do gradle, é preciso adicionar um .jar direito na lib.